# Can you pass a block of code that returns an error to a method?

Tags: ruby, methods, error-handling, nokogiri, rescue

I often find myself dealing with these kind of scenarios:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require "open-uri"

url = "https://www.random_website.com/contains_info_I_want_to_parse"
nokodoc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
# Let's say one of the following line breaks the ruby script
# because the element I'm searching doesn't contain an attribute.
a = nokodoc.search('#element-1').attribute('href').text
b = nokodoc.search('#element-2').attribute('href').text.gsub("a", "A")
c = nokodoc.search('#element-3 h1').attribute('style').text.strip
```

What happens is that I'll be creating about 30 variables all searching for different elements in a page, and I'll be looping that code over multiple pages. However, a few of these pages may have an ever-so-slightly different layout and won't have one of those div. This will break my code (because you can't call .attribute or .gsub on nil for example). But I can never guess which line before-hand.
My go-to solution is usually surround each line with:

```
begin
  line #n
rescue
  puts "line #n caused an error"
end
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
url = "https://www.random_website.com/contains_info_I_want_to_parse"
nokodoc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

catch_error(a, nokodoc.search('#element-1').attribute('href').text)
catch_error(b, nokodoc.search('#element-2').attribute('href').text.gsub("a", "A"))
catch_error(c, nokodoc.search('#element-3 h1').attribute('style').text.strip)

def catch_error(variable_name, code)
  begin
    variable_name = code
  rescue
    puts "Code in #{variable_name} caused an error"
  end
  variable_name
end
```

I know that putting & before each new method works:

```
nokodoc.search('#element-1')&.attribute('href')&.text
```

But I want to be able to display the error with a 'puts' in my terminal to see when my code gives an error.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass your `code` as a regular argument to a method because it'll be evaluated (and raise an exception) before it gets passed to your `catch_error` method. You could pass it as a block--something like

```
a = catch_error('element_1 href text') do 
  nokodoc.search('#element-1').attribute('href').text
end

def catch_error(error_description)
  yield
rescue
  puts "#{error_description} caused an error"
end
```

Note that you can't pass `a` to the method as `variable_name`: it hasn't been defined anywhere before calling that method, so you'll get an `undefined local variable or method` error. Even if you define `a` earlier, it won't work correctly. If your code works without raising an exception, the method will return the right value but the value won't get stored anywhere outside the method scope. If there is an exception, `variable_name` will have whatever value `a` had before the method (`nil` if you defined it without setting it), so your error message would output something like `Code in  caused an error`. That's why I added an `error_description` parameter.

You could also try logging the message and backtrace if you didn't want to have to specify an error description every time.

```
a = catch_error(nokodoc) do |doc|
  doc.search('#element-1').attribute('href').text
end

def catch_error(doc)
  yield doc
rescue => ex
  puts doc.title # Or something else that identifies the document
  puts ex.message
  puts ex.backtrace.join("\n")
end
```

I made one additional change here: passing the document in as a parameter so that `rescue` could easily log something that identifies the document, in case that's important.